# ASP.Net SQL Insert Doesn't Happen and No Errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

So I am still sort of new to ASP.Net.  I have created a web form that an end user fills in. They then click a submit button and the data is SUPPOSED to be inserted into a SQL DB.

When you click the submit button, the popup alert window appears saying "a new record was added," but when I query the DB in management studio, the new record is not there.  And to make things even weirder I get no errors anywhere. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    Dim par_db_connstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PAR_DB_Conn").ConnectionString
    Using sqlConn = New SqlConnection(par_db_connstring)
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(SqlStatment, sqlConn)
            'Adding paramaters
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parNum", par_Number)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parDate", parDate_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submittedby", submittedby_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", ddlArea_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentstatus", ddlStatus_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_num", jobNum_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", customer_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mfg_cost", mfgcost_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_cost", invcost_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_type", problemType_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_description", problem_description_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action_required", actionRequired_Ins)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrective_action", correctiveAction_Ins)

            Try
                If sqlConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    sqlConn.Open()
                End If
                Dim recAff As Integer = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + recAff.ToString() + "')</script>")
            Catch generatedExceptionName As SqlException
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + generatedExceptionName.ToString() + "')</script>")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim insMsg As String = "New PAR Record Added..."
    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + insMsg + "')</script>")
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { window.close();}</script>")
```

Here is the connection string:
     `<add name="PAR_DB_Conn" connectionString="Data Source=O-SN-2I-LT-101\SQLEXP14;Initial Catalog=PAR;User ID=<User ID>;Password=<Password>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Don't know why the connection string didn't post but here it is:

Comment: <add name="PAR_DB_Conn" connectionString="Data Source=O-SN-2I-LT-101\SQLEXP14;Initial Catalog=PAR;User ID=<User ID>;Password=<Password>"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see what command is being executed, and post it.

Comment: Have you checked text of `SqlStatment`?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the INSERT statement that is being executed...

Comment: Missing sqlCmd.CommandText = "InsertStoredProcedureName"
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure